# How can I trigger a php function?

Tags: php, function, triggers

I want to trigger a php function like this-

***"If I click Here"*** (it can be a button or link)

// then this function would work:

```
<?php
function a(){
$b=10;
echo $b;
}
?>
```

How can I do that without ajax ? (I don't want to reload the page.You can show me way to put that php function inside javascript too if required)

-Thanks.

***"Edit" :*** Would it be possible by php cURL ?

Comment: You cant. PHP runs on the server!

Comment: You _must_ use AJAX, or reload the page. PHP and JavaScript in the client browser have no knowledge of one another.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done in PHP without reloading the page or using Ajax. The only alternative is converting that piece of PHP code to Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function a()
{
  var b = 10;
  document.write(b);
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="a();">
```

Comment: I want php. may be mixed with javascript but not total javascript.

Comment: Well, then you have to use Ajax or reload the page. Good luck.

Comment: No, you still need Ajax to call your PHP curl function. Then you might as well use Ajax to call you PHP function directly without using curl.

Comment: I see, yes if still requires ajax then no need to use curl.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Code example.php:

```
<?php

function a()
{
    $b=10;
    echo $b;
}

if (isset($_GET['run_func']))
{
    a();
}

?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href='example.php?run_func=a'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I don't wanna reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is client side language (executes in browser), while PHP is server side (executes on the server). To execute the PHP  a [REQUEST](http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest) has to be made on the server

This can be done by visiting a url, or by invoking ajax call (which does the request)

If you want to execute a function or a call you have to make a request to that php file.

So, you put code in my_php_fle.php and then do a request via link

```
 <a href="my_fle.php"> If I click Here </a>
```

However, you will have no result as you still have to make a call to php function.So, your my_file.php needs to look like this

```
<?php
function a(){
    $b=10;
    echo $b;
}
 a(); //executes your function
?>
```